# Django. DetailView simple validation. Check weather user has a subscription

Tags: python, django

When user requests object, when user wants to enter detail view's page, I want to check weather user have subscription and redirect him. But I don't know how to request user and validate him in DetailView. This is what at least I could did.

```
class PropertyDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = Property
    template_name = 'project/property/property_detail.html'

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.sale_tariff is None:
            return redirect('/')
```

Are there any ways how to validate DetailView?

Comment: Override the GET request not POST

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the get request something like this

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.request.user.sale_tariff is None:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(template_name)
```